# How to enable "use settings from VCS" option for Versioned Settings in Team City?

Tags: devops, teamcity, cicd

I am trying to achieve behavior as many other CICD tools do: the configuration of the build to be used from the current branch which triggered the build.

Currently it is not clear how to enable and select "Use settings from VCS" option as the option "use current settings by default" is always enabled by default when I enable synchronization.

[image]

TeamCity VCS root configuration: [image]

Answer (score 0):

Try to disable sync first and then enable it, before saving you can change your settings.